# cursor skips every other row

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have a cursor that works but skips every other record. My fetch next looks like this

```
OPEN DemandCur
While 1 = 1
BEGIN

    FETCH NEXT FROM DemandCur INTO
    @----,
    @+++++

    select @index = (select demand from TechCoDemand where Date = '2014-11-30') 

    IF @index <= 0 BREAK;   

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK;

    FETCH NEXT FROM DemandCur INTO 
    @---,
    @++++
End

Close DemandCur
Deallocate DemandCur
```

I changed it to

```
FETCH NEXT
```

And it stopped skipping records but I get an error message after the query is done:

> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Line 121
>   A cursor with the name 'NEXT' does not exist.

Comment: those are the worst variable names I've seen

Comment: DLeh, Those are not the actual variable names.

Comment: Wheres your first Fetch? This looks fine.

Comment: You need to show more code.

Comment: I added the first part of the fetch cursor

Comment: You should only be calling `fetch next` once inside the loop.

Comment: Martin, Are you saying the second fetch should be removed or should it just be Fetch DemandCur?

Comment: The usual pattern is     `FETCH NEXT ...;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      Print 'do something'
      FETCH NEXT ...;
    END`

Comment: the first `FETCH NEXT` should be before `WHILE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have alluded to in the comments above, you're fetching twice within your while loop. While (ha!) you do need to "prime the pump" (so to speak) by fetching one row outside of the while loop first, here's an idiom that I like to use to avoid that entirely.

```
declare cursor foobar for
select ...

open foobar

while(1=1)
begin

    fetch next from foobar into ...
    if (@@fetch_status <> 0)
       break

    --process results

end

close foobar
deallocate foobar
```

This has the benefit of only having to have one fetch statement to maintain but, more germane to this conversation, avoids your error entirely.

Comment: Thanks Ben Thul.  That worked perfectly.  I was under the impression that you always have to have a second fetch statement from all the codes I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this....

```
OPEN DemandCur
FETCH NEXT FROM DemandCur INTO @----, @+++++
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    select @index = (select demand from TechCoDemand where Date = '2014-11-30') 
    IF @index <= 0 BREAK;   
    FETCH NEXT FROM DemandCur INTO @---, @++++
END

Close DemandCur
Deallocate DemandCur
```